# While Iterating over a tasks array in a component in NEXTJS 13.3.0 I am getting same error that tasks.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, react-typescript, next.js13

> I am fetching the object using an api and passing the tasks fetched to TaskList component in which i have defined the props with an TodoListProps which receives an array but when I am trying to iterate over tasks(props) I can't do that and shows same error everytime
> In same component when i console log it. it shows all the objects present in the tasks array.
> Not sure what I am doing wrong here and it is not suggesting me anything to use with tasks while using dot operator , I have defined all the types and props and still same error

> **TaskList.tsx**  This is the component where I am receiving error

```
import { ITask } from "../types"

interface TodoListProps {
    tasks : ITask[]
}

const TodoList : React.FC<TodoListProps>   = (tasks)  => {
    console.log(tasks);
  return (
    <div className="overflow-x-auto">
  <table className="table w-full">
    {/* head */}
    <thead>
      <tr>
     
        <th>Name</th>
       
        <th>Favorite Color</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     
    {tasks.map((task : ITask)=>(

      <tr key={task.id} >
        <td>{task.text}</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
   
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
  )
}
```

> page.tsx This component pases the task to Todolist as a prop after fetching them

```
import TodoList from "@/components/TodoList";
import Addtask from "../components/AddTask";
import { getAllTodos } from "@/api";
import { ITask } from "@/types";


export default async function Home() {
  const tasks : ITask[] = await getAllTodos();
  return (
    <main className="max-w-4xl mx-auto mt-4 ">
      <div className="text-center my-4 flex flex-col gap-4">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Todo List App</h1>
      <Addtask />
      </div>
     <TodoList tasks={tasks}/>
    </main>
  )
}
```

> **types.ts** Defined type of receiving data

```
export interface ITask {
    id: string,
    text: string
}
```

//data I am receiving in console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94FRw.png)

// Error I am receiving
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzfuE.png)

Comment: While you fetching tasks e.g. await getAllTodo() the tasks are undefined likely

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
const TodoList : React.FC<TodoListProps> = (tasks)  =>
```

The variable `tasks` will be an object containing all properties you are passing in to the component.  Instead try

```
const TodoList : React.FC<TodoListProps> = ({tasks})  =>
```

now `tasks` will contain only the tasks property.